# How to iterate over the keys and values in an object in CoffeeScript?

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

I have an object (an "associate array" so to say - also known as a plain JavaScript object):

```
obj = {}
obj["Foo"] = "Bar"
obj["bar"] = "Foo"
```

I want to iterate over `obj` using CoffeeScript as follows:

```
# CS
for elem in obj
```

bu the CS code above compiles to JS:

```
// JS
for (i = 0, len = obj.length; i < len; i++)
```

which isn't appropriate in this case.

---

The JavaScript way would be `for(var key in obj)` but now I'm wondering: **how can I do this in CoffeeScript?**

Comment: "Arrays" in JavaScript/CoffeeScript are special objects with numerical indices and a `length` property that simply refers to the highest numerical index (plus 1). What you want is just an "object": `obj = {}`. Arrays are objects, but there's no reason to use one in your example.

Comment: Good point Trevor! I've modified the question to be a bit less misleading/confusing in this regard.

Answer (score 354, accepted):

Use `for x,y of L`. [Relevant documentation](http://coffeescript.org/#loops).

```
ages = {}
ages["jim"] = 12
ages["john"] = 7

for k,v of ages
  console.log k + " is " + v
```

Outputs

```
jim is 12
john is 7
```

You may also want to consider the variant `for own k,v of ages` as mentioned by Aaron Dufour in the comments. This adds a check to exclude properties inherited from the prototype, which is probably not an issue in this example but may be if you are building on top of other stuff.

Comment: Precisely. CoffeeScript's `of` compiles to JavaScript's `in`. It's a common point of confusion, but having `in` for use with arrays is incredibly useful. I talk about this at length in [the CoffeeScript book](http://pragprog.com/titles/tbcoffee/coffeescript).

Comment: You should not initialise `arr` as `arr = []`, you should use `arr = {}`. In Javascript (and Coffeescript) arrays have numeric indices. Objects behave like associative arrays/dicts.

Comment: Thanks, that's been pointed out by Trevor and others already, and my answer was keeping to the original question code. I'll update my example to use a plain object for clarity anyway.

Comment: Although it doesn't matter for this particular example, it sounds like `for own key, value of obj` is closer to what OP is looking for.

Answer (score 4):

You're initializing an array, but then you're using it like an object (there is no "associative array" in js).

Use the syntax for iterating over objects (something like):

```
for key, val of arr
  console.log key + ': ' + val
```

Comment: Actually, *all* objects in JS are associative arrays (sans consistent key ordering). So the code jcmoney gave should work, though there's no reason to use `[]` instead of `{}` in that case.

Comment: http://jashkenas.github.com/coffee-script/#loops looks like the loop generated by coffeescript will not iterate over object-members.

Answer (score 3):

The short hand version using array comprehension, which can be used as a one-line loop.

```
console.log index + ": " + elm for index, elm of array
```

Array comprehension are:

> "Comprehensions replace (and compile into) for loops, with optional
>   guard clauses and the value of the current array index. Unlike for
>   loops, array comprehensions are expressions, and can be returned and
>   assigned.", 
>   http://coffeescript.org/#loops

Comment: please explain. merely providing a code snippet isn't sufficient. stackoverflow is not a "gimme the codez" site, the idea is that others will benefit more if the answer provides a clarification of the abstract concept.

Answer (score 1):

with your convention, arr is an array, but "foo" is a property of this array, it is not an indexed value.
If you want to store your data the indexed values of an array, you should have written :

```
arr1 = []
arr1[0] = "Bar"
arr1[1] = "Foo"
```

or if you want an associative array, just use an object :

```
arr2 = {}
arr2["Foo"] = "Bar" // equivalent to arr2.foo="Bar"
arr2["bar"] = "Foo" // equivalent to arr2.bar="Foo"
```

if you want to loop over arr1 :

```
str = "values are : "
for val in arr2
  str += val + " |"
console.log key + ': ' + val
```

returns :

```
values are : Bar | Foo |
```

and to loop over arr2 : "for value in array"

```
for key, val of arr
  console.log key + ': ' + val
```

which returns :

```
Foo : Bar
Bar : Foo
```