# iterating over method names in coffeescript

Tags: coffeescript

In JS, I can do something like this:

```
for(i in MyClass.prototype) {
  console.log(i);
}
```

And it will show me the method names. That's fine.

Now, if I do this with coffeescript:

```
for i in MyClass.prototype
  console.log i
```

It will be compiled to:

```
var i, _i, _len, _ref;

_ref = MyClass.prototype;
for (_i = 0, _len = _ref.length; _i < _len; _i++) {
  i = _ref[_i];
  console.log(i);
}
```

But prototype doesn't have a `length` property, so, it breaks.

How can I make it with coffeescript?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6408726/iterate-over-associative-array-in-coffeescript

Comment: thanks to your link I figure it out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 'secret' is to use the `of` command when using objects:

```
console.log i for i of MyClass.prototype
```