# How convert JSON to CoffeeScript and write on a file ".coffee"?

Tags: json, coffeescript

How convert JSON to CoffeeScript and write on a file ".coffee" with NodeJS?

JSON:

```
{
  "name": "jack",
  "type": 1
}
```

to CoffeeScript:

```
"name": "jack"
"type": 1
```

Comment: Why would you want to do that?!

Comment: Huge fan of coffeescript and I agree with Neal, there's no good reason to do this. JSON in "js" form is entirely compatible with coffeescript. If you want to reshape the object then that is a different question.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

I hope you know how to read and write files in nodejs, so i will not address that here.
To convert javascript to coffeescript you can use this npm:

https://github.com/rstacruz/js2coffee

Answer (score 2):

Should be easy enough by traversing the object ([`for … of`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6408726/iterate-over-associative-array-in-coffeescript)). Just use recursion and take the indent level as an argument:

```
esc_string = (s) ->
  return '"' + s.replace(/[\\"]/g, '\\$1') + '"'

csonify = (obj, indent) ->
  indent = if indent then indent + 1 else 1
  prefix = Array(indent).join "\t"
  return prefix + esc_string obj if typeof obj is 'string'
  return prefix + obj if typeof obj isnt 'object'
  return prefix + '[\n' + (csonify(value, indent) for value in obj).join('\n') + '\n' + prefix + ']' if Array.isArray obj
  return (prefix + esc_string(key) + ':\n' + csonify(value, indent) for key, value of obj).join '\n'
```

Test case:

```
alert csonify
  brother:
    name: "Max"
    age:  11
    toys: [
      "Lego"
      "PSP"
    ]
  sister:
    name: "Ida"
    age:  9
```

Result:

```
"brother":
    "name":
        "Max"
    "age":
        11
    "toys":
        [
            "Lego"
            "PSP"
        ]
"sister":
    "name":
        "Ida"
    "age":
        9
```

<sup><s>No live demo, since I don't know a JSFiddle for CoffeScript.</s></sup>

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/vtX3p/